# How do I sum several rows by category? (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, categories, sumifs

I have created an excel sheet to have an overview over costs in my projects, however, I also need an overview of costs per category in my projects. I googled it and tried to find examples online, however, it only returns a value of 0, which shouldn't be the case. Can anyone help me? The sheet looks like below.

[image: Excel Sheet]

I am going by the SUMIF function to group by category but my excel sheet is a bit more complex than that so I tried to adjust it accordingly as seen in the code below. No matter what I do it either returns an error or 0.

```
=IF(B12=B8;"";SUMIF(B12:B39;B12;J12:BE39))
```

In the formula above I am trying to sum the costs of a category that could be written in B12, for example, Software development. For confidential reasons, I cannot show the actual filled out excel sheet.

Comment: Instead of real data, you might want to fill that out with some dummy data and show us instead. Either way, why are you comparing e.g. `Software development` to cell `B8` being the header?

Comment: Showing a blank worksheet without showing where went wrong and/or what you want to achieve is not helping.

Comment: It's alright, I got the answer I needed from someone here. Thanks though!

Comment: In that case you should mark the question as answered. Check how to under Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sumif` does not work with summing multiple columns. Instead use a `sumproduct` statement instead like so:

```
=IF($B12=$B$8;"";SUMPRODUCT(($B$12:$B$39=$B12)*($J$12:$BE$39)))
```

A detailed explanation to how this works [can be found here](https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-one-criteria-multiple-columns)

**Edit:**
I sense a follow up question coming, how to skip certain columns. Because as you have set it up now, it will count the entire range from `J12` to `BE39`, in which you have both forecast costs and actual costs. I guess this is to compare the costs to what was projected and what the actual costs are. Right now it will count both the projected and actual cost, doubling up. To prevent this you can enter every second column separated by a `+` like so:

```
=IF($B12=$B$8;"";SUMPRODUCT(($B$12:$B$39=$B12)*($J$12:$J$39+$L$12:$L$39+$N$12:$N$39)))
```

Also I have added $ signs to all non-changing values so it will work when dragging down the fill handle on the formula to populate the below cells.

Comment: Is there a way to do it per actual column as well for example? Also, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: See my edit, I knew this was coming so I was writing it before you asked ;)

Comment: @Tina Might be redundant, but you can also easily adjust this formula to sum the actual costs as well instead of the forecast, if this is a comparison you also want to make. You do this by adjusting all he columns you count (in the last pair of brackets) up by one letter.

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks a lot! I adjusted it to all the actual columns and it works perfectly - a bit redundant yes but it does the job :) Thanks a lot, you made my day!

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm always happy to help. Feel free to accept my answer if this resolves your question, for everyone else who might stumble across it. Also I tried making it less complicated by adding a named range instead of naming every column, but then it does not recognize the columns as separates in this range and returns an error. So naming every column is the way to go sadly.